# SQL Command to save a table to text file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to save some values from a table to a text file using C# and a SQL command

```
sql.connection.Open();
sql.ex = new SqlCommand("EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._RefPackageItem" queryout "textBox1.Text" -T -c '",sql.connection);
sql.ex.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql.connection.Close();
```

I did that into my C# api but I don't know how to fix the error in `SqlCommand` text? Can anyone provide the needed fix ?
http://prntscr.com/1b5b2b

Comment: What exactly would that error be???

Comment: well it puts a red line under the 2nd line

Comment: When you try to execute it, what error does it throw?  If you hover over the underlined text, does it give you an explination?  Anything more specific?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/1b5b2b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are liberally mixing double quotes needed by the bcp command with double quotes needed to delimit you command from the textbox variable. And, as you can see, the red squiggle is the way used by the syntax checker of VS to tell you that it is not happy with that.

Put a backslash in front of the quotes needed for the bcp command and add a + operator to concatenate the string value of the textbox to the remainder of your command

```
sql.ex = new SqlCommand("EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp \"SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._RefPackageItem\" queryout " + 
         textBox1.Text + " -T -c '",sql.connection);
```

Let me say also that string concatenation to build Sql Commands is a very dangerous practice.
When using normal commands to query and/or update data I would recommend to absolutely avoid string concatenation because you could be exposed to Sql Injections. In this case I am not sure if a Sql Injection command could be mounted using the contents of TextBox1.

Answer (score 0):

```
char b = '"';
string a = string.Format("EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp {0}SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.._RefPackageItem{0} queryout " + textBox1.Text + " -T -c '",b);
```

Comment: If you are using string.Format why still use the `+`?